# Aggregate Root complexity in Domain-Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Where does one draw the line in the complexity of an aggregate? To clarify, if my aggregate has a list of ObjectA which has a list of ObjectB which has a list of ObjectC, should my aggregate be responsible for retrieving ObjectC? Or should I be looking at creating another aggregate to keep this complexity down to a couple of levels in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases the boundaries of the Aggregate should be the consistency boundaries needed for your model. That means that if changes to ObjectA or B or C need to be consistent with each other than they probably belong to the same Aggregate.

The complexity ( business logic complexity ) should be handled by identifying all the concepts in the domain and splitting the behavior across the entities/VOs involved.

The object retrieving complexity (infrastructure complexity) should be handled by the infrastructure and not by the aggregate.

In conclusion model you ARs according to your domain and to your consistency boundaries and not to facilitate infrastructure concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, I take it that the way objects are retrieved is an infrastructure concern. But wouldn't that be necessary in determining which entities should be AR? In some cases it'd be logical to access ObjectB from ObjectA aggregate root, but in another context/use case ObjectB could very well be it's own aggregate root. So wouldn't infrastructure concerns be a determining factor after all?

Comment: Infrastructure concerns should not dictate your AR boundaries. Your consistency requirements should. The idea is that a Concept in your domain can be an AR in one bounding context and an entity in another bounding context. Accessing an entity directly defeats the hole purpose of having Aggregates - which is to enforce invariants and consistency. I recommend you watch [Eric Evans video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-eric-evans) and after that, re-read the chapter about Bounding Contexts from the DDD book. Your use cases are a good start for determining the BCs

Answer (score 1):

Like lulian says I guess there is no rules that says how your AR's should look like. If your AR with ObjectA, B and C belong to same business context its fine. But I think you should also reflect on how your clients/use cases are using your model. If you always want the ObjectC's and the object graph traversal from ObjectA and B down to C feels like an unnecessary traversal, maybe your model is incorrect.

If your root object is ObjectA and you have a ObjectARepository you can always add repository methods like GetObjectCsByObjectA(ObjectA objectA) that will list all C's for an A.
If a ObjectC can be child to several ObjectB that above solution maybe isn't the best one since you get all C's for one A.

Must most important is how your GUI/clients will use this AR (repeat myself...)
You can add extension methods for adding Linq filters or searches to ease the traversal from A to C. Not my favorite but it works. Better can be to try to wrapp ObjectB's collection in ObjectA with either a Value Object or just a simple listwrapper class that is not persisted and is just created when accessing this collection. This wrapper can provide the necessary access methods that suits your GUI and also validations when adding, replacing and deleting list items. The wrapper will be a shortcut for your clients so they do not need to bother how AR is built up inside AR.

Do ObjectB and ObjectC has any associations to other entities outside this AR?

Comment: You're right, after reading responses the rule is that it's completely contextual. I'd have to agree with you that determining AR is a process that isn't only coupled with the domain boundaries, but also use cases. I don't see how I'd ever know if any object in my aggregate could be an aggregate by itself without looking at use cases. To answer your last question, yes ObjectC does have other associations outside of AR.

Comment: A Common guideline is that all Child objects within an AR should not have associations outside AR boundaries. Why? Well if you want to remove/delete the root instance all its AR child objects should also be removed. That can be a tricky operation if child is like your ObjectC that has external associations. Maybe you need to upgrade ObjectC as an AR with its own repository? Child entities can be AR them self within other AR's.

Comment: "Parent/child" can be ambiguous.  Following Evans model an AR *cannot* be both an AR and a member of another AR.  Two ARs can have a relationship.  External objects can only reference AR but Entities in an AR can hold external refs. A list of ObjectC in ObjectA does not confer aggregate membership.  If ObjectC is truly  an AR it is an AR-AR relationship.  If ObjectC is truly part of the ObjectA AR, ObjectC cannot also be an AR.  The existence of a reference to ObjectC from ObjectA alone is not enough to differentiate the two possibilities. AR is conceptual, cannot be expressed solely by code.